# How to compute min, max, average from an array?

Tags: c, arrays

This is the original question asked:
1.The user will input up to 20 numbers, and these numbers will be stored in an array. Write functions  will take as input and return the minimum, the maximum, and the average. Use the functions to compute the min, max, and average of the array.

Here is what I have but I dont know why it is not working, any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>


void arrmin(int a[],int num_elements);
void arrmax(int a[], int num_elements);
void arraver(int a[],int num_elements);

int main(void)
{
   int a[20],c,min,max;
   float avg;
   printf("Enter 20 numbers of elements in array\n");
for (c = 0; c < 20; c++)
    scanf("%d", &a[c]);

   min=max=a[0];
arrmax(a,a[20]);
   printf("Maximum value is %d\n", max);


arrmin(a,a[20]);
   printf("Minimum value is %d\n", a[20]);

  arraver(a,a[20]);
   printf("Average value is %f\n", a[20]);

   getch();
}

void arrmax(int a[], int num_elements)
{
   int i, max;
   for (i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
   {
   if (a[i]>max)
   {
        max=a[i];
   }
   }

   return(max);
}
void arrmin(int a[], int num_elements)
{
   int i, min;
   for (i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
   {
   if (a[i]<min)
   {
        min=a[i];
   }
   }

   return(min);
}

void arraver(int a[], int num_elements)

{ int sum,i;
float avg;
   sum=0;
avg=0;

   for (i=0; i<num_elements;i++)
   {
   sum=sum+a[i];
     avg=(float)sum/(i+1);
      }
return(avg);
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) then use a debugger (`gdb`) and a memory leak detector ([valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)...)

Comment: And read about undefined behavior and be very scared from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic looks pretty good, but there are a few small issues. The fixed code is given at the bottom of the answer.

**Issues:**

1. Pass `20` to the second argument of `arrmax`, `arrmin`, and `arraver`

   - `arrmax(a,a[20]);` becomes `arrmax(a, 20)`.
2. You probably want the `arr...` functions to return `int` or `float` rather than `void`

   - `void arrmax(...)` becomes `int arrmax(...)`
   - `void arraver(...)` becomes `float arraver(...)`
3. Be sure to actually use the values returned by your functions

   - `arrmax(a,20);` becomes `max = arrmax(a, 20);`, etc.
4. Be sure to initialize `max` and `min` variables in their respective functions.

   - `max = a[0];`
   - `min = a[0];`
   - now we can iterate from 1 to 19 instead of 0 to 19
5. The `min` and `aver` printers should print `min` and `aver` rather than `a[20]`.

   - `printf("Min is %d\n", a[20]);` becomes `printf("Min is %d\n", min);`
   - `printf("Average is %f\n", a[20]);` becomes `printf("Average is %f\n", aver);`

**Fixed code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arrmin(int a[],int num_elements);
int arrmax(int a[], int num_elements);
float arraver(int a[],int num_elements);

int main(void)
{
   int a[20],c,min,max;
   float avg;
   printf("Enter 20 numbers of elements in array\n");
   for (c = 0; c < 20; c++)
      scanf("%d", &a[c]);

   max = arrmax(a,20);
   printf("Maximum value is %d\n", max);

   min = arrmin(a,20);
   printf("Minimum value is %d\n", min);

   avg = arraver(a,20);
   printf("Average value is %f\n", avg);

   getch();
}

int arrmax(int a[], int num_elements)
{
   int i, max;
   max = a[0];
   for (i=1; i<num_elements; i++)
   {
      if (a[i]>max)
      {
         max=a[i];
      }
   }

   return(max);
}

int arrmin(int a[], int num_elements)
{
   int i, min;
   min = a[0];
   for (i=1; i<num_elements; i++)
   {
      if (a[i]<min)
      {
         min=a[i];
      }
   }

   return(min);
}

float arraver(int a[], int num_elements)
{
   int sum,i;
   float avg;
   sum=0;
   avg=0;

   for (i=0; i<num_elements;i++)
   {
      sum=sum+a[i];
      avg=(float)sum/(i+1);
   }
   return(avg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was just wondering why is it necessary to use max = INT_MIN; and min = INT_MAX;

I tried running the code without these additions and it works

Comment: @AlexisHolguin - Uninitialized integers can have any value. Imagine you call `arrmax` with an array of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 20. If you use `int max;`, max could have the initial value of `1000`. Since none of your numbers are greater than 1000, the function would return the incorrect value of 1000.

The reason it worked in your case is that *usually* uninitialized values randomly get the value 0, but that is not guaranteed

An alternative is setting `max` and `min` to `a[0]` - I edited my answer to suggest that instead.

Comment: I see, I really appreciate your help. I've been struggling with it, but it is finally working thank yoyu very much

Comment: Glad to help! If this or any other answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!